# How to amend latest commit whilst keeping the same commit message

Tags: git

I have edited a file and committed a message.

```
git add file
git commit -m "corrected spelling mistakes"
```

After the commit, I've now realised there was another spelling mistake in `file` which I promptly correct but for the sake of tidiness I want the latest spelling mistake correction to be part of the previous commit message. Is there a command that I can use to absorb the changes I make into the last commit?

*Note: I have not pushed any changes to a remote repository.*

Comment: Take a look at [`git commit --amend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend)

Comment: If you don't want to change the message, you can add `--no-edit` too.

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks should I `git add file` again before running `git commit --amend --no-edit` ?

Comment: I have an alias for that: `fixup = !git add -u && git commit --amend -C HEAD`

Comment: +1 for `--amend -C HEAD`. I prefer to name the alias something like `amendl` (amend-last), `amendt` (amend-top) because `fixup` is a reserved keyword in git (`git commit --fixup`)